# Создать из большого текста список списков

Tags: c#, linq

Ребята такая проблема: Задание с он-лайн курсов ulearn.

> "В этот раз мы проведем обработку текста. Наша конечная цель —
>   алгоритм продолжения текста, который по нескольким введенным словам
>   угадывает наиболее вероятное следующее на основе знаний, полученных
>   при анализе большого текстового массива. Вся задача разбита на 3
>   этапа: подготовка текста, анализ частотности биграмм и собственно
>   продолжение текста, на основе информации о частотности. В этой задаче
>   вам нужно разбить текст на предложения, а предложения на слова.
>   Выполните задание в классе SentencesParserTask."

Собственно сам файл с заданием снизу. Продублирую код сюда.
Я попытался сделать задание с помощью LINQ, оставил комменты, что делает каждый метод.
Ошибку выдает такую:

```
Error on: a b, c 0th element (subitems delimited by pipe symbol) should be [b|c], but was [b,|c]
```

Заранее спасибо за помощь!)

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace TextAnalysis
{
    static class SentencesParserTask
    {
        public static readonly string[] StopWords = 
        { "the", "and", "to", "a", "of", "in", "on", "at", "that", 
          "as", "but", "with", "out", "for", "up", "one", "from", "into" };
        /*
        Разбейте файл с текстом на предложения и слова. 
        Считайте, что слова могут состоять только из букв 
(используйте метод char.IsLetter) или символа апострофа ',
        а предложения разделены одним из следующих символов .!?;:()
        Удалите из файла слова, содержащиеся в массиве StopWords (частые незначащие слова при анализе текстов называют стоп-словами)
        Метод должен возвращать список предложений, где каждое предложение — это список оставшихся слов в нижнем регистре.
        */
        //StopWords.Select(b=>b)
        public static List<List<string>> ParseSentences(string text)
        {
            var sb = new StringBuilder(text);

            var lstStr = sb.ToString()
                .Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')')//разделяем строку символами тем самым преобразуется до предложений
                .Select(a => a.Split(' ').Except(StopWords)//разбиваем предложения по пробелу и удаляем из предложения множество StopWords
                //и проверяем является ли символ буквой, в нижнем ли регистре буква или символ апострофа
                .Where(b => b.Any(c=>char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsLower(c) || c=='`'))
                .Select(b => b).ToList()).ToList();

            return new List<List<string>>(lstStr);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ребята и ещё поясните как правильно форматировать код, чтобы корректно оставлять вопросы? А то пробовал по инструкции сайта и что-то криво вышло

Comment: А вы непременно хотите это сделать с помощью `LINQ`?

Comment: ну не то, чтобы, просто дело в том, что я только начинаю изучать LINQ и хотелось бы разобрать именно как данный пример можно сделать с помощью LINQ) Конечно Если вы скажите как будет правильнее организовать решение данной задачи и с точки зрения рефаткоринга и с точки зрения производительности - я буду очень Вам признателен)

Comment: Эко, вы завернули; с производительностью и рефакторингом! Я так понимаю, вы можете написать, но хотите написать не просто, а с маленьким извращением в стиле brainfuck. Тогда я тоже подожду, может чего наклюнется :)

Comment: А эту часть: "...анализ частотности биграмм ..." вы уже написали?

Comment: А нет, там задания идут последовательно и это первая часть задания)Все задание состоит из 3-х частей, я просто посмотрел с помощью отладки и не вижу каких-то проблем  с работой данного кода. Но вот чеккер на ulearn почему-то не принмаиет мое решение) Спрашивали на киберфоруме - там не смогли помочь)

Comment: Ошибочная проверка: `.Where(b => b.Any(c=>char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsLower(c) || c=='`'))`

Comment: Посмотри, должно ли проходить эту проверку слово `b,`? Ну и на слова ты неправильно делишь, такого слова как `b,` не должно быть :-)

Comment: Я пробовал переделать запрос вот так:

 var lstStr = text
                .Split('.', '!', '?', ';', ':', '(', ')')
                .Select(a => a.Split(' ',',','\n','\r').Except(StopWords)
                .Where(b => b.Any(c=> char.IsLetter(c) && char.IsLower(c)
                &&char.IsLower(b[0]) || c=='`'&& char.IsLetter(c) 
                && char.IsLower(b[0]) && char.IsLower(c)))
                .Select(b => b).ToList())
                .Where(z=> z.Count!=0).Select(z=>z).ToList();

Comment: @ФилиппБаринов, вообще непонятно что написано. Но ты понял в чем у тебя проблема?

Comment: Извините, я просто тут недавно. Как вставлять участок кода в комменты? Не могу найти что-то этой инфы.

Comment: Вот насчет слова "b". Вы говорите, что оно не должно проходить эту проверку, но почему? Это слово оно берется из уже отсортированного множества и каждое слово проверяется нижний ли регистр его букв или если есть в слове апостров и слово в нижнем регистре. Я просто уже пару дней пытаюсь разобраться с этим заданием.

Comment: В комментарии код лучше вообще не вставлять. Смотри внимательнее о каком слове я говорю. про `b` я ничего не писал.

Comment: Тогда я Вас, увы, не понимаю

Comment: `b` - это совсем не то же самое что `b,`

Comment: Просто ещё один момент в том, что я уже переделал код немного и хотел бы Вам его показать, но как это делается на Stack`е?) и в переделанном мною коде уже совсем другая ошибка.

Comment: Здесь два варианта, так как пока тут никто не дал ответ, можно отредактировать текущий вопрос. Либо, удалить этот вопрос, и задать новый

Comment: Окей, я тогда задам наверно новый вопрос. Но все равно мне не совсем понятно, что вы сказали) Вы имели ввиду, что последняя выборка Select(b=>b) выбирает слова, а должны быть списки?

Comment: @ФилиппБаринов, нет, я имел ввиду, что ты неверно получаешь слова, и вместо слова _b_ получил `b,`